# How to connect a iPhone tether hotspot and use Wi-Fi on windows 10 laptop?

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, wireless-router, iphone

I work on remote industrial sites. I bring a router with me to tie machines together and be able to hit the individual machines over the routers Wi-Fi network.

I used to be able to have my iPhone tehtered with USB (for internet) and connect to the wifi router (isolated router not internet access) at the same time. Now when I plug in my iPhone it connects to the internet like normal but it is turning my laptops wifi connection off and I am unalble to turn it back on.

Network Connection settings:

[image: Network Connection settings]

If I click the Wi-Fi button in the bottom left it seems like it tries to turn on but then goes back to the same setting (shown in picture). I used to do this no problem but I was digging around in my BIOS the other day trying to figure out virtual machine stuff and I must have changed something to cause this or is there a setting some where in Windows that can resolve this?

Comment: Try:  Not tethering, but set up an iPhone Hotspot.  Check Allow Users to Join. Then multiple users should be able to join.  I do this for one or two computers and it works fine.

Comment: @John I need my laptops Wi-Fi signal to be hooked to the router so I can hit the machines that are connected to the router. If I hook it to my phones Wi-Fi hot spot then I won’t be able to connect to the router. The machines that are tied to the router don’t and shouldn’t have internet access because they are industrial machine controllers. Plus I have had both tether and Wi-Fi working for years with no problem. I must have changed a setting by mistake

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found the BIOS setting that caused my issue. I don't remeber checking the box but I must have. Heres a picture of the BIOS screen.

[image: HP zBOok Bios Settings]